# how to fill the right column first and then the left in a 2-column layout

Tags: css

I have 5 div elements (in a simplified manner here). How can I set css to make a 2-column layout with the first 2 divs on the right and the rest divs on the left like shown in the picture (each div element can be identified with different classes or ids if needed)? The number of divs on the right or left can be fixed and known ahead of time, rather than dynamically flew. The 2 columns may have different heights, but they need aligned on the top (i.e. div3 and div1 start from the same vertical position). Ideally, I don't want to set a fixed height on either each div elements or on the left or right column.

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

[image]

Comment: My opinion check bootstrap grid system, it is very simple

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uLq42ejb/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Set `display:flex` on the container

2) Set flex container's main-axis as the block-axis with `flex-direction: column;` (see [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction))

3) Switch wrap direction with `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` (see [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap))

Note: This will only work correctly if the container has a fixed height. (thanks @Paulie_D)

Demo:

```css
.wpr {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wpr div {
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 6%;
}
.wpr div:nth-child(n+3) {
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

---

Since the OP added clarifications that:

1) The wrapper may not have a fixed height

2) The number of divs on the right can be fixed (say 2)

we can implement this with floats by floating (and clearing) the first 2 divs

```css
.wpr {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flow-root; /* create new block formatting context */
  /* Note: if ie/edge support is required use overflow: hidden
           instead of display: flow-root */
}
.wpr div {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 35%;
}
.wpr div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  color: red;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div>1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard </div>
  <div>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type </div>
  <div>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy when an unknown printer took a g </div>
  <div>4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </div>
  <div>5 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this requires a fixed height

Comment: `flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;` is also equivalent to `flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

Comment: That's a bummer. I can't set a fixed height on the container. I edited the question to relax the requirement a bit - is this height restraint overcomable if I specify exact 2 div elements on the right?

Comment: @RNA I added an additional way which might work for you

Answer (score 2):

I did using `grid` CSS. Here is the [Pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/NWPgvqZ).

**HTML**

```
<div class="parents">
  <div class="child box-1">
    <img src="https://w3bits.com/files/img/cherry-plant.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child box-2">
    <img src="https://w3bits.com/files/img/oranges-pomegranates.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child box-3">
    <img src="https://w3bits.com/files/img/strawberry.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child box-4">
    <img src="https://w3bits.com/files/img/blueberries.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="child box-5">
    <img src="https://w3bits.com/files/img/pears.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parents{
  direction: rtl;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: initial;
  column-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.parents .child{
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  direction: ltr;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parents .child img{
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.parents .child.box-1{
  height: 300px;
}
.parents .child.box-2{
  height: 300px;
}
```

**If you want to masonry view**. HTML and CSS in [Pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/WNbOEjb).

**Editing ANS after question change for auto height**

`column` auto `height` will work if you change your `html` like this.

```
<div class="item-group">
    <div class="item-group-left">
        <div class="item-box">
            <p>Item 1</p>
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/500/winter" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-box">
            <p>Item 2</p>
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/500/home" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-group-right">
        <div class="item-box">
            <p>Item 3</p>
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/tree" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-box">
            <p>Item 4</p>
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/fish" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-box">
            <p>Item 5</p>
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/rock" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Auto `height` HTML and CSS is [here](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/XWJgejB).

If you don't want to change `html` then you have to set a fixed based `height`(based `height` `100px`). Then you will able to increase item `height` using `grid`. Also you will able to set First and Second item on right side. [Pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/abzwyxK).

**CSS**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 15px;
}
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* Based height. Change if you want */
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.item{
  display: inline-block;
}
.item.item-1{
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.item.item-2{
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}
.item.item-3{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.item.item-4{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.item.item-5{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}
img{
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your solution needs fixed height. I edited the question to relax the requirement a bit - is this height restraint overcomable if I specify exact 2 div elements on the right?

Comment: @RNA I add two more example. One for auto `height` and another `fixed` based `height`. If you change your `html` structure then auto `height` will work perfectly.